# take rows that start with a specific string and add them to the row before - bat file..windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd

so i have a file  like this

```
03,01234567,,015,+000000021541435,,

88,015,5000000,,Z/ ,,091918 
88,015,10192716,,Z/ ,,091918

03,10222222,,010,+000000000723925,,,015,+000000000752750,,/ ,,091918 

88,066,0,,,015,-200240,,/  

03,0345678,015,33963635,,,901,33963635,,/                                                                                                                                    
88,066,0,,,015,0,,/
```

what i need to do is to merge the 88 rows with the 03 row on top of it. the first line of the new file should be

```
03,01234567,,015,+000000021541435,,88,015,5000000,,Z/ ,,091918,88,015,10192716,,Z/ ,,091918
```

and so on.

all i have is

```
@echo off
(
  for %%F in (TRSF.SUM) do (
    for "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /b /c:"88," "%%F"') do echo %%F %%A
  )
) >newfile.SUM
```

and it not working at all.

Comment: Please indent your code and data with 4 spaces to preserve whitespace and line feeds. You can also highlight the entire block and hit the `{}` at the top of the editor. I have taken care of the edit this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this is to collect the lines into a single variable. I used ALINE. ALINE is set whenever the first two characters are "03". All other records are appended to ALINE until a "03" is encountered.

You might note that some of the data lines in your question have spaces at the end of the line.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "FN=multirows.txt"
SET "ALINE="

FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('TYPE "%FN%"') DO (
    SET "THISLINE=%%a"
    SET "RECTYPE=!THISLINE:~0,2!"

    IF "!RECTYPE!" == "03" (
        IF NOT "!ALINE!" == "" (
            ECHO !ALINE!
            SET "ALINE="
        )
        SET "ALINE=!THISLINE!"
    ) ELSE (
        SET "ALINE=!ALINE!!THISLINE!"
    )
)

IF NOT "%ALINE%" == "" ( ECHO %ALINE% )
```

Comment: Thank you so much @lit! This code seem to be working. I was hoping you can help me get the result into a new file. right now it just displays on the dos prompt. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: `@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "FN=TRSF.SUM"
SET "ALINE="

FOR /F "delims=" %%k IN ('TYPE "%FN%"') DO (
    SET "THISLINE=%%k"
    SET "RECTYPE=!THISLINE:~0,2!"

    IF "!RECTYPE!" == "03" (
        IF NOT "!ALINE!" == "" (
            ECHO !ALINE!**>>newfile.SUM**
            SET "ALINE="
        )
        SET "ALINE=!THISLINE!"
    ) ELSE (
        SET "ALINE=!ALINE!!THISLINE!"
 
    )
)

IF NOT "%ALINE%" == "" ( ECHO %ALINE% )`

Comment: struggling with formatting the code as i'm new to this.  but the newfile.sum  is the new file. and it worked!! you saved me. Thank you very much again!

Comment: There is no need to write to a specific file in the .bat file. If the name of the .bat file is `doit.bat`, then use `doit.bat >"newfile.SUM"`.